# ubuntu remove package actually installs other dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, apt

On ubuntu when I use apt remove to delete a package, it will actually also install/update other dependency packages.

Of course, that is not desired, so I'm wondering how can I remove the package and ignore any other dependencies from being installed?

I don't have aptitude, so all I was looking is around apt/apt-get but couldn't find any flags.
These might be dependencies from removal, but let's say to just completely ignore those and just remove what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [dpkg](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dpkg.html.en) as "it cannot automatically download and install packages or their dependencies". Also take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/173996/694900) which could be helpful for what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @UdonN00dle
"dpkg --remove --force-depends" seems to be the solution in my case.
It explicitly says it's breaking the dependencies, but it might just be enough for me.